# convert a char element from an array to an int

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

Hi I'm trying to convert elements of an array into integers using input from the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char i[9]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','\0'};
    int j;
    printf ("enter an integer for an element ");
    sscanf(i, "%d", &j);

    return 0;
}
```

I read somewhere that using sscanf is one way to do it but I don't know the correct way to use it.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf or `man sscanf` on a linux/osx box

Comment: Once you figure that out, heed the return result of `sscanf` and act accordingly, else fall into the pit of violating [Henry Spencer's Sixth Commandment](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). By the looks of that input string, you're going to need it.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads from the standard input.

`sscanf` reads from a string.

Example of `scanf` usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str1[20];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("First char converted to int: %d\n", str1[0]);

   int j = str1[1];
   printf("Second char converted to int: %d\n", j);

   return(0);
}
```

Input and Output:

```
Enter name: marcel
First char converted to int: 109
Second char converted to int: 97
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marcel said, there are two different functions that do different things.
You request *convert elements of an array into integers using input from the user*, so I can think you want this:

```
char i[9]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','\0'};
int j;
printf ("enter an integer for an element ");
scanf("%i", &j);
printf("Element[ %i ] in integer is: %i", j, i[j]);
```